# Out of the remaining numbers i wanted to choose some numbers but based on a certain counter variable whose value is randomly determined

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array that holds numbers from 1 to 7. Now i am selecting specific numbers and putting it on another subarray. If it doesn't contain those specific numbers i wanted to choose some numbers but based on a certain counter variable whose value is randomly determined. That is for example if counter value is 2 only two numbers from the remaining array elements must be chosed.
This might be a simple question but i need help as i am a beginner to ios and objective c

thanks in advance
what i have tried is

```
int counter = (arc4random()%(4-1))+1

for(int i=0; i<[mainarray count];i++)
{
    if([[[mainarray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1] integerValue]==specificnum)
    {
        [subarray addObject:[mainarray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    else if(counter==1)
    {
        [subarray addObject:[mainarray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

i am actually stuck in the else part

Comment: Post what you have tried so far and point out what issues you are having.

Comment: can you put an example describing your whole requirement

Comment: Please can anyone help me out i am not able to move any further.

Comment: what happened? send me mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am here showing arrays with sample values. Try this

```
int counter = (arc4random()%(4-1))+1;
    int specificnum = 4;
    NSLog(@"Counter:%i ",counter);

    NSArray *mainarray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7", nil];
    NSMutableArray *subarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(int i=0; i<[mainarray count];i++)
    {
        if([[mainarray objectAtIndex:i]  integerValue]==specificnum)
        {
            [subarray addObject:[mainarray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        else if(counter!=0)
        {
            [subarray addObject:[mainarray objectAtIndex:i]];
            counter--;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Array: %@",subarray );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] mainarray;
int[] subarray;
```

//suppose you have moved some array elements from mainarray to subarray.

//find present array length of main array

```
int main_length=mainarray.length();
int subarray_length=subarray.length();
Random rand = new Random();

int counter== rand.nextInt(main_length) + 1;

for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
{
subarray[subarray_length]=mainarray[counter];
subarray_length++
}
```

Comment: there is a slight editing in the question..It is not out of the remaining elements. if it doesnt contain that specific number then we have to choose elements based on counter variable.